# Vertically aligning div with fixed div as a parent?

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment, absolute

I have a relatively div positioned on top of a fixed position div and I would like to vertically align this first div. Is there a way to do this? This is my current markup:

```
<div class="overlay">
    <div id="dialogInvoice">
        content
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#dialogInvoice {
    width: 390px;
    height: 722px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}
```

Any suggestions on this? I did try the line-height method but this is apparently only working when using mere text.

Comment: Can you draw an example of your objective?

Comment: https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-VkKe-DFuEsw/TYTXFh3fJuI/AAAAAAAABRI/9rBS08RlJJc/s1600/Screen+shot+2011-03-19+at+9.47.03+PM.png

Comment: Does #dialognvoice need to be "position:relative"?  You can do it if you use position:absolute and set a top: 100px and bottom:100px maybe

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your element does not have a fixed width or height then you can't use the other solutions without using javascript to calculate the values.

Here is an alternative.

```
#dialogInvoice {
    width: 390px;
    height: 722px;
    padding-top: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

Comment: Never would've thought of this solution... thank you!

Answer (score 1):

what you need to add to your css of `#dialogInvoice` is

```
top: 50%;
```

and change the margin to

```
margin: 361px auto;
```

(361 is 722 / 2)

it will first push your container half way down the page and then push it back up the required value, which is exactly half of its height (361px)

here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/PK546/) for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

This CSS may do what you require:

```
.overlay {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 10;
}

#dialogInvoice {
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding-top: 28px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #ffffff;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    bottom:100px;
    left:100px;
    right:100px;
}
```